# set a (method) breakpoint for a particular object (and not all instances of that type) in java

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Suppose I have a class

```
public class Foo
{
     public void doThing() { ...}
}
```

Say I have a lot instances of `Foo`, but I'm only particularly interested in one of them.

How would I "tag" that instance and set a "conditional breakpoint" in `doThings` that would stop ONLY for the tagged instance?
Is there a "builtint" way, particularly by the Eclipse debugger, to do this?

Currently, I have to manually create a boolean flag in the `Foo` class setting  it to false by default, and create a conditional breakpoint based on that in `doThings`.
Then when I encounter the interested object, I would set the flag to `true` by executing the setter code in the `Display` window.

But clearly, that requires modifying the code and adding some boilerplate, which is not always possible or a good thing to do.

Comment: I am not sure it is what you are asking, anyway, the feature has been available for long time. Start debugging, and when the breakpoint stops on your desired object instance, click on "this" in the debug variables view, then "instance breakpoints"; you get the list of live instances and you can choose on which to restrict the breakpoint

Comment: @guido That sounds like what he's asking for to me. You should add that as an answer.

Comment: @erickson i am not sure because this only works at runtime after starting the debug sessions and the instance is already available, it seems he wants to decide which instance it is before that, at compile time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is instance breakpoints in Eclipse.

You have to *put a common breakpoint in the desired class* and, in the variables panel, you right-click on the instance and choose **Instance Breakpoints**.

[image: Instance Breakpoints]

A popup will ask you which breakpoint you want to active for that instance.

[image: Popup Selection]

You choose and it's done!

[image: Done]

Answer (score 2):

Not the cleanest way, but you can set a conditional breakpoint on the default `Object#toString` output of the instance.

After getting the default `toString()` result of the instance, add something like the following as a breakpoint condition in the `doThing` method:

```
this.toString().equals("Foo@184ec44")
```

Comment: Well, this depends on `toString` NOT being overriden. But thanks, for answer!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any "proper" way, but one approach would be to call `hashCode()` in the watch window when you first create it, and then make the breakpoint conditional on the `hashCode()` as well. So you'd need to change the break point each time you ran it - somewhat annoying, but it does at least give you a constant value that you can use to refer to the object. (That's assuming the class doesn't override `hashCode()`, of course - if you've got many instances with the same hash code, that makes things trickier.)